# Why this reverse function isn't working?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, reverse

Why isn't this working?
ps. I don't want to use any other variable to make it work, and i don't want to use built in functions, just asking why THIS is not working?

```
function reverse(arr){
  for(var i =0; i< arr.length; i++){
    arr.push(arr[arr.length-i]);
  }
  return arr;
}
```

Comment: Do you know what `arr.push(arr[arr.length-i]);` does

Comment: @AlexanderMac When you see the question and code, you must not give this comment.

Comment: @Alexander Mac I want to reverse without using any other variable, is that possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [ask] and **[mcve]**

Comment: @Tusher I'm learning, so maybe i really don't know how that works, maybe i think i know but i really don't know. That's why i asked :)

Comment: @RobertLock **No.** But yes, using a built-in function. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of flaws in your code.

- When you start pushing `arr.push(arr[arr.length-i]);` the array length increases, thereby, you won't get a consistency in the data.
- This goes inside an infinite loop, as every time, the `arr` is ahead of its length.

It is better to use another variable and reverse, or you can use the built-in `reverse()` function. There's nothing wrong in having another variable and add temporary contents in it.

**Solutions:**

> Using a temporary array:

```
function reverse(arr) {
    var final = [];
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        final.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return final;
}
```

> Using [built-in function (`Array.prototype.reverse()`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse):

```
function reverse(arr) {
    return arr.reverse();
}
```

> Using few temporary variables:

```js
a = [5,4,3,2,1];
function reverse(arr) {
  var i = 0, j = arr.length - 1;
  for (i = 0; i < j; i++, j--) {
    var temp = arr[i];
    arr[i] = arr[j];
    arr[j] = temp;
  }
  return arr;
}

console.log(reverse(a));
```

Comment: @RobertLock Welcome. May I know what's the main reason you need to "not" use a temporary variable?

Comment: i'm reading Eloquent JS and there's an exercise that goes like this: "The first, reverseArray, takes an array as argument and produces a new array that has the same elements in the inverse order. The second, reverseArrayInPlace, does what the reverse method does: it modifies the array given as argument in order to reverse its elements. Neither may use the standard reverse method.

Comment: so, basically i've to write two functions, and i still cant write the second one

Comment: @RobertLock Oh okay... That's actually crazy, coz it is not possible at all. Or, if you really wanna use only one variable or one array? Coz we can use it in a different way with only a single array.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't want to use any other variable to make it work, and i don't want to use built in functions

You cannot.

---

Use temporary array for result

```
function reverse(arr) {
    var res = []
    for (var i = arr.length - 1; i > -1; i--) {
        res.push(arr[i]);
    }
    return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're going to run out of memory.  What you're doing is adding what was initially the last element of that array infinitely to the end of your array. Every time that you call `arr.push(...)` you increase `arr.length` by one.  Your for loop will never be able to finish because `i` will never be less than `arr.length`